# How do I round the value my function outputs?

Tags: python, rounding

I'm writing a code which converts knots to km/h.

```
def to_kmh(knots):
  # Calculate the speed in km/h
  return 1.852 * knots
 
# Write the rest of your program here
knots = float(input('Speed (kn): '))
if to_kmh(knots) <60:
  print(f'{to_kmh(knots)} - Go faster!')
elif to_kmh(knots) <100:
  print(f'{to_kmh(knots)} - Nice one.')
elif to_kmh(knots) >=100:
  if to_kmh(knots) <120:
    print(f'{to_kmh(knots)} - Radical!')
if to_kmh(knots) >120: 
  print(f'{to_kmh(knots)} - Whoa! Slow down!')
```

I'm trying to round the output (km/h) to 1 decimal place. Example: When I type in '3 knots' on the program I get:

```
5.556 - Go faster!
```

Whereas I would like to get

```
5.6 - Go faster!
```

I've tried using

```
def to_kmh(knots):
  # Calculate the speed in km/h
  return 1.852 * knots
  round(to_kmh, 1)
```

in the function, but that outputs the same result (5.556).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only round when displaying, and you can achieve it like this using `:.1f` on your f-string variables:

```py
def to_kmh(knots):
    # Calculate the speed in km/h
    return 1.852 * knots
 
# Write the rest of your program here
knots = float(input('Speed (kn): '))
if to_kmh(knots) <60:
    print(f'{to_kmh(knots):.1f} - Go faster!')
elif to_kmh(knots) <100:
    print(f'{to_kmh(knots):.1f} - Nice one.')
elif to_kmh(knots) >=100:
    if to_kmh(knots) <120:
    print(f'{to_kmh(knots):.1f} - Radical!')
if to_kmh(knots) >120: 
    print(f'{to_kmh(knots):.1f} - Whoa! Slow down!')
```

Another option, to avoid the repetition, would be to make your `to_kmh` return the formatted string instead of a number.

Or, if you really want to round the number from the function (it is not guaranteed that the result will be what you want):

```py
def to_kmh(knots):
  return round(1.852 * knots, 1)
```

Your mistake was that your tried to `round` after `return`.

Comment: question - what is .1f

Comment: In summary, the syntax for rounding decimal places is `.Nf` where `N` is the number of decimal places you want. For example, you would use `.2f` for `5.56`. For a more detailed explanation, it is the fixed-point used on the format function, you can find more details here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `round()` before the `return` statement. In a function, anything after the `return` statement is executed is not executed.

So change your code to

```
return round(1.852 * knots, 1)
```

it should work fine !!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the rounding when returning the value, do it when formatting the output.

```
kmh = to_kmh(knots)
if kmh <60:
    print(f'{kmh:.1f} - Go faster!')
elif kmh <100:
    print(f'{kmh:.1f} - Nice one.')
elif kmh <120:
      print(f'{kmh:.1f} - Radical!')
else:
    print(f'{kmh:.1f} - Whoa! Slow down!')
```

There's also no need to test `>= 100`, since that's ensured by the previous `elif`. And the final test should just be `else:` to get all higher values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for improving the conciseness

Comment: question - what is .1f

Comment: `f` means to format as a floating point number, and `.1` means 1 digit after the decimal.